# How to add line breaks in a cell after comma in a data frame

Tags: r, csv

I have a csv file that contains multiple values in some cell, for example:

```
example<- c("a, b", "c", "d", "e, f", "g")
data.frame(example)

  example
1 a, b
2    c
3    d
4 e, f
5    g
```

And I want it to look like this with line breaks after those cells with multiple values separated by commas

```
  example
1    a, 
     b
2    c
3    d
4    e,
     f
5    g
```

Comment: Do you want lines in separate rows? `df <- data.frame(example)` and `tidyr::separate_rows(df, example)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you just need a simple replacement here using `sub`:

```
example <- c("a, b", "c", "d", "e, f", "g")
df <- data.frame(example)
df$example <- sub(",\\s*", ",\n", df$example)
df

  example
1   a,\nb
2       c
3       d
4   e,\nf
5       g
```

Note that although R console might not be rendering the `\n` newline characters as actual newlines, the newlines are actually there (and will show up, for example, if you write out your data frame to a text file).

Comment: It will be difficult to get things to line up properly. For this example, adjusting the third line to `df$example <- sub(",\\s*", ",\n     ", df$example)` and adding `cat(paste(1:5, "  ", df$example), sep="\n")` gets pretty close.

Comment: @dcarlson You are assuming that the OP wants the formatting to be done within R, which isn't even clear based on the question.

Comment: Also, to answer @dcarlson response I don't care about the format, just want the line break. Thanks for providing the code anyways!